# How to use left clause in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

this is my query for find all records in table and sort from the oldest. I want to limit one column to only 50 characters. I can't find any information how to change this query for use left clause.

```
    $posts = $ChocoPosts->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'));
```

Additionally i tried use clean sql syntax for that, but it's not show any records.

```
 $conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();
$sql = '
    SELECT id, title, left(content, 45), date_add, img
    FROM choco_posts
    ORDER BY id DESC
    ';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->fetchAll();
```

I'm using symfony4 ant twig template. I display all records in twig for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `SUBSTRING` statement, as example:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT id, title, SUBSTRING(content, 1, 45), date_add, img
    FROM choco_posts
    ORDER BY id DESC
    ';
```

By itself there is little difference, however left can potentially utilize an index while substring cannot.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. use twig slice filter - https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html
2. map results - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
3. or if you want use object create metohd with substring

Comment: Thank you so much! Slice solve my problem! C: Dzięki wielkie :3